# How can I improve my Codeforces solution? It shows time limit exceeded

Tags: c++, performance

I got a time limit exceeded error on a Codeforces Question (test case #28).

The link is http://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/525/B
The solution is nowhere to be found on google.
Does anyone have any idea regarding making  this solution a bit faster.

My Code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str[2000005];
    scanf("%s", &str);
    long long l = strlen(str);
    long long k, i, j, days, pos, counter = 0;
    scanf("%I64d", &days);
    for (k = 1; k <= days; k++) {
f:
        cin >> pos;
        counter++;
        i = pos - 1;
        j = l - pos;
        // swap(str[pos - 1], str[l - pos])
start:
        swap(str[i], str[j]);
        i++;
        j--;
        if (i <= j)
            goto start;
        else if (i > j && counter < days)
            goto f;
        else if(counter==days)
            break;
    }
    printf("%s", str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s;
    int m, i, a[200002];
    cin >> s >> m;
    while (m--) {
        cin >> i;
        a[i]++;
    }
    int net = 0, n = s.length();
    for (int i = 1; 2 * i <= n; i++) {
        net += a[i];
        if (net % 2) swap(s[i - 1], s[n - i]);
    }
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Suggestions:

1. Don't use `goto` if time limits are specified, use `for` or `while`
2. Look for warnings in your code
3. `long long` was unnecessary in this case
4. Formatting code properly helps a lot in debugging
5. Don't mix C I/O and C++ I/O, read [this blog](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/10)

**EDIT**: There is no need of reversing the string every time. We need to count how many reverses will begin in every position of string. Read this [blog entry](http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/17119) for more.

Comment: Thanks Shreevardhan. But it still shows a TLE on your code :(